# issus in code to find the total number of distinct nodes visited, considering all possible paths in undirected patt

Tags: algorithm, recursion, graph

Hi i am facing a problem -

Given a undirected graph, source and destination, write the code to find the total number of distinct nodes visited, considering all possible paths.

and i have a recursive solution but i am not sure about its CORRECTNESS .

```
HashSet<String> mConnectedNodes;
Stack<String> stack;

public void findNodesOnAllConnectingPaths(Node startNode, Node endNode) {
    stack.push(startNode.getValue());

    // Check for the base case = finding destination node on path
    if (startNode.getValue() == endNode.getValue()) {
        Enumeration<String> currentElements = stack.elements();
        while(currentElements.hasMoreElements()) {
            mConnectedNodes.add(currentElements.nextElement());
        }
        stack.pop();
        return;
    }

    //Recurse if any connected nodes aren't on the current path
    ArrayList<Node> nodes = startNode.getConnectedNodes();
    for (Node node : nodes) {
        if (!stack.contains(node.getValue())) {
            findNodesOnAllConnectingPaths(node, endNode);
        }
    }
    stack.pop();
    return;
}
```

please suggest me test cases where it can fail and a good source for the algorithm for  ALL SIMPLE PATHS IN UNDIRECTED GRAPHS.

Comment: Are you looking for all simple paths? or all vertices that there is a path between the source to them? If you are interested in vertices - you need a discover algorithm, such as [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) or [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)

Comment: amit what u think about that code , is it correct?? do you have a good source from where i can get these algos in better  way???

Comment: First answer which of the two you want to do, they are different things, only after understanding what you are after, i'll be able to examine the code/

Comment: the code is for fining different certices came in any path from source to target .

Comment: @Dukeling no i am not sure about that one . I want to know about fastest and good algo for this.